# howto import packages in local packagist.org installation by command

Tags: git, composer-php, gitlab, packagist

**Scenartio:**

We have an internal packagist.org installation for our private repositories. These packages/repositories are hosted on our privat GitLab-server.

As we have a lot of packages (~150 and counting) it would be great to to add these by an automated command, that will register them.

**Problem:**

I've wrote an command that will call the GitLab API to fetch a list of all repositories. That works very well so far.
Now i'm at the point where i have to import these Git-URLs into our packagist, but i can't find a service or controller with an complete example of how to do that.

I found the **WebController** where the "magic" happens, but i don't find the point where the repository gets called to fetch the remote composer.json file (to find the package name etc).

I hope anyone can point me the way! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing my own method for that, if you need this too, you can grab the code here:
https://gist.github.com/sweikenb/dc800442db8d0647bdbe